# Add Atten property in Unity Shaderlab

Tags: unity, shaders

In Unity Shaderlab shader, Is there any way to apply _Atten value?
Using surface shader, and vertex/fragment shader I can do it easily. 
But, I didn't find any reference to do that in Shaderlab syntax.

```
Shader "Diffuse" {
    Properties {
        _Atten ("Light Attenuation Power", Float) = 1.0 // <= how to apply?
        _Color ("Main Color", Color)            = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB) Transparency (A)", 2D) = "" {}
    }
    SubShader {
        Pass {
            SetTexture[_MainTex]
            {
                  constantColor [_Color]
                combine texture * constant, texture * constant
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this makes syntax error.

```
constantColor [_Atten * _Color]
```

Comment: Are you initializing the _Atten property inside of your CG code?  Is that the entirety of your Shader code?

Comment: It's not CG, it's shaderlab Jon. So, it doesn't need to declare or initialize the variable. yes, it's the entire shader code.

Comment: try [_Atten] * [_Color]

Comment: tried [_Atten] * [_Color]. Parse error. T_T / _Atten * [_Color] also makes parse error.